# Writing to 2 seperate BLE devices with same Tx Characteristics

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, c++-winrt

I am using Windows 10, VS 2019, C++, WinRT

I have a questions about writing to a Tx characteristic after I have connected 2 devices with the same Tx characteristics.  I want to control 2 identical BLE devices separately.  I have all of the code in place for connecting and running 1 of these devices but as I studied my existing code I don't see that the characteristic write refers to a particular device object.

The device objects are created with

```
auto device1 = co_await BluetoothLEDevice::FromBluetoothAddressAsync(deviceAddress1); // Same with device2
```

I then get the main service and the Tx and Rx characteristics which are the same for device1 and 2.

After setting up the writer with

```
auto writer = Windows::Storage::Streams::DataWriter();
```

and then filling in the command to be written with

```
writer.WriteString(wstrCommand);
```

I then do the actual write to the Tx characteristic with

```
status = co_await TxCharacteristic.WriteValueWithResultAsync(writer.DetachBuffer(),
winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::GenericAttributeProfile::GattWriteOption::WriteWithoutResponse);
```

To which device would this command be sent?  Am I leaving out a reference to the device1 or device2 object?

**Edit**
Is it that the TxCharacteristic object contains the Service object with contains the deviceID and therefore if I write to TxCharacteristic1 and 2 it will write to the proper device?  I guess I will have to do the code and find out.

Thanks.

Ed

Comment: Do you have test results? Is the transmitted data a broadcast effect?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to get back to do the actual coding to check it out.  The problem is that the MS docs make you click around quiet a bit to get an overall picture.  I clicked around some more and I am pretty sure that I was mistaking the TxCharacteristic object with the actual Uuid.  According to the docs, the Characteristic object contains a Service property and the Service contains a property for the DeviceId.  So, since one is writing to the Characteristic object and not just the Uuid, that by default, is writing to the proper DeviceId associated with that Characteristic object.

Comment: Once I have verified this with code I will answer my own question to finalize it.  Hopefully today but at least by this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the Characteristic **object** will write to the device object from which it was read.  My original mistake was to be thinking of the characteristic as the GUID and forgetting that in WinRT the characteristic is an object that contains properties (one of which is the Uuid) which contain properties.  I have not looked at the WriteValueWithResultAsync code but it appears that the code will direct the write to the characteristic of the device associated with that characteristic so you need to keep the characteristic objects separate.

What I had to do was alter my memory variable names from TxCharacteristic to TxCharacteristic1 and TxCharacteristic2 and, of course, put in a lot of if...else clauses. I also had to create RxCharacteristic1 and RxCharacteristic2 and to create 2 separate Rx callbacks.  Live and Learn.